# cannot reset the Mysql root password in windows 10

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

actually i forgot the **mysql** root password, i tried to reset the password but not getting proper responses.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'myPassword';
```

Comment: What is your error message ?

Comment: i forgot the mysql server root password, tried with different queries but i can't reset the password.

Comment: I solved. link is [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html]